# Condition for monos out of an initial object to be isos.

Tags: category-theory

What does one need to assume in a category $\mathcal{C}$ with an initial object $0$, so that every morphism $f:0\to A$ out of $0$ (I am not assuming anything on the object $A$) satisfies the property that:

**whenever $f$ is a monomorphism it is necessarily an isomorphism** ?

Are there any natural examples of such categories?

Comment: Is there any specific motivation for that question?

Comment: @Hanno Was afraid of that question - I am clearly avoiding it above. Well, none other motivation except that I have a general construction of a category in which I want that property to hold, and it is not clear at that abstract level that it does. So ideally I want to reduce it to some other property that I might be more confident with...

Comment: Of course, it's not true in Set or in its dual; it is true in the one-point category.

Comment: In an abelian category, $0$ is also terminal, so every parallel pair $x, y: X \to 0$ is actually the same arrow. So $fx=fy$ always implies $x=y$, so every arrow from $0$ is monic; so any abelian category with more than one object is not an example.

Comment: @PatrickStevens ... and so is every other category where $0$ is terminal, like the category of groups, rngs, monoids, pointed sets, ...

Comment: And any category where the only morphisms with codomain $0$ are isomorphisms... Categories where $f:0\to A$ is *not* monic are kind of peculiarities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If every monomorphism out an initial object $0$ is an isomorphism, then every object is (canonically) isomorphic to $0$, i.e. the category is an **[indiscrete category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/indiscrete+category)**, i.e. two objects have exactly one morphism between them.

To see this, first consider an initial object $0$ every monomorphism out of which is an isomorphism. Then $0$ is a **strict initial object**, i.e. any morphism $A\to 0$ is an isomorphism. Indeed, for any morphism $A\to 0$, the composite $0\to A\to 0$ is always the identity morphism by universal property of initial object. Consequently, $0\to A$ is a (split) monomorphism out the initial object, hence by assumption an isomorphism. But then $A\to 0$ is a right inverse *of an isomorphism*, hence is itself an isomorphism.

Second, observe that if $0$ is a strict initial object in a category, then it is also **subterminal**: any morphism from an object to $0$ is unique. Indeed, given $B\underset g{\overset f\rightrightarrows} 0$, since $f$ and $g$ are both isomorphisms, we must have that $0\xrightarrow{f^{-1}}B\xrightarrow{g} 0$ is the identity morphism, hence $g$ is the inverse of $f^{-1}$, i.e. $f$.

Consequently, in a category with a strict initial object $0$, every morphism out of $0$ is (vacuously) a monomorphism since any pair of morphisms $B\rightrightarrows 0$ is a pair of identical morphisms. Thus, if every monomorphism out of an initial object is an isomorphism, then every morphism out of $0$ is an isomorphism. Hence, an initial object has a unique isomorphism with every other object, so all objects are initial, so any two objects have exactly one morphism between them.